# How do abduction and induction relate?

Tags: reference-request, induction

1. Is abduction a species of induction? Can we abduce what we could never know by induction?
2. And has anyone tried to enumerate what we can know by induction?

Comment: [Deduction, Induction and Abduction on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abductive_reasoning#Deduction.2C_induction.2C_and_abduction)

Comment: that's not going to tell me anything new, i'm not asking how to define the terms, but if abdution reduces to induction

Comment: You're question whether abduction is a specie of induction can be answered by carefully reading that paragraph.

Comment: ok answer the question if you can / like mahn :) ?

Answer (score 3):

See [Abduction](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/) :

> The term “abduction” was coined by [Charles Sanders Peirce](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce/) in his work on the logic of science. He introduced it to denote a type of non-deductive inference that was different from the already familiar inductive type.

[...]

> the best way to distinguish between *induction* and *abduction* is this: both are *ampliative*, meaning that the conclusion goes beyond what is (logically) contained in the premises (which is why they are non-necessary inferences), but in abduction there is an implicit or explicit appeal to explanatory considerations, whereas in induction there is not; in induction, there is only an appeal to observed frequencies or statistics.

Comment: so it definitely doesn't collapse into induction ?

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN - it is induction+explanation.

Comment: what i was trying to get it is whether abduction tells us something we cannot induce. i assume so?

Comment: This is an open issue as far as I'm aware, with people arguing for either side. Personally, I see abduction to collapse into induction, since the value behind the abductive choice can usually only be justified inductively.

Comment: @MMB what is meant be the "value behind the abductive choice"?

Answer (score 3):

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nn3XMoPC7s) distinguished and explained most clearly for me:

[image]

For a textual explanation, and the 3 words' etymology and etymological definitions, see https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/deduction-vs-induction-vs-abduction

> If you have trouble differentiating deduction, induction, and abduction, thinking about their roots might help. All three words are based on Latin ducere, meaning "to lead." The prefix de- means "from," and deduction derives ***from*** generally accepted statements or facts. The prefix in- means "to" or "toward," and induction leads you ***to*** a generalization. The prefix ab- means "away," and you take ***away*** the best explanation in abduction.

and

http://www.digitalpeirce.fee.unicamp.br/p-abachi.htm.